# How to add next and previous buttons to image galary

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know the question has been asked and I've searched and searched on here but a) i can't seem to figure out how to adapt what I've found and b) i have another small issue to go along with trying to add the next and previous buttons to my gallery-ish layout.

Here is the link to my page:

http://mymediaculture.com/_broadway_branding/index2.html

The second problem is that i'm using a pure css fadein/out transition effect, for my images but I can't find a way to make the first image of the gallery show when the page loads.

As you can see, I already have the next/previous links in place. Just don't know enough about js/jquery to make them work.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

html

```
 <div id="top_mid_mid">
    <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="#">
        <img id="mypicture" border="0" alt="portfolio" src="images/recent/recent1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <div id="prev"><a class="current" href="#"  title="portfolio"><img  alt="prev" src="images/prev.gif" id="prevlink" /></a></div>
        <div id="next"><a class="current" href="#"   title="portfolio"><img  alt="next" src="images/next.gif" id="nextlink" /></a></div>

</div>
```

javascript

```
window.onload= recent_pic;
window.onload= toogle;

var mypix=new Array("images/recent/recent1.jpg","images/recent/recent2.jpg","images/recent/recent3.jpg","images/recent/recent4.jpg","images/recent/recent5.jpg");

var thispic = 0;

function recent_pic(){
    document.getElementById("prevlink").onclick=processprev;
    document.getElementById("nextlink").onclick=processnext;

        document.getElementById(1).onclick =  one;
        document.getElementById(2).onclick =  tow;
        document.getElementById(3).onclick =  three;
        document.getElementById(4).onclick =  four;
        document.getElementById(5).onclick =  five;

}

/******************for arrow ****************/
function processprev(){
    if(thispic==0){
        thispic=mypix.length;
    }
    thispic--;
    document.getElementById("mypicture").src= mypix[thispic];
    return false;
}

function processnext(){
    thispic++;
    if(thispic==mypix.length){
        thispic=0;
    }
    document.getElementById("mypicture").src= mypix[thispic];
    return false;
}

/******************for arrow end****************/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done complete bins for Image slide show with Previous and Next Buttons using jQuery. I think this Demo should be helpful for you, so the demo link as below.

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8x

**HTML:**

```
<div class="topbar">
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li id="previous">
      <a href="#tag">
        Previous
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">
        1
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        2
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        3
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        4
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        5
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        6
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        7
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        8
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        9
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        10
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="next">
      <a href="#tag">
        Next
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="images">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://thumbs.myopera.com/sz/colx/Mathilda%C2%B4s%20Wallpaper/albums/104123/Animal%20Friends.jpg" width="250" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://marowall.ru/Jivotnie/Grizuni/Kroliki1024/8/9.jpg" width="250" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://www.mejoresmascotas.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/perrito.jpg" width="250" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://data.whicdn.com/images/16010691/white_lion_large.jpg" width="250" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://koprol.zenfs.com/system/mugshots/0153/9924/index.jpg" width="250" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Cute-Squirrel-s.jpg" width="250" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://thumbs.myopera.com/sz/colx/adilsaadi/albums/5861552/horses.jpg" width="250" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://fundartspring2011.wikispaces.com/file/view/puppy_dogs_14.jpg/217071218/297x225/puppy_dogs_14.jpg" width="250" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zfT5EAh0Tz8/TbJVRf5wywI/AAAAAAAAAE4/TWWdSLhx9Io/s1600/ardilla.jpg" width="250" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://thumbs.myopera.com/sz/colx/skafridi/albums/6474892/animals-pictures-birds-bluebird.jpg" width="250" height="200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .topbar{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:35px;
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #B0832E;
  border-shadow:1px 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-size:12px;
  width:100%;
  z-index:9999;

}

#navigation{

  border: 1px solid red;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 5px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: 3;
}
#navigation li{
  display:inline-block;
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border:1px solid white;
  color:#444444;
  font-size:12px;
  text-transform:uppercase;

}
#navigation li a{
  color:#444444;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:2px 5px;
}
#navigation li.active a, #navigation li:hover a{
  color:#fff;
  background:#333;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
#images{
  text-align:center;
}
.slide{
  padding:5px;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:35;
  margin-left:25%;
  background:#2255a9;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    //Show Current Active Image Slide On Document Ready
    showSlide();

    $("li", $("#navigation")).click(function() {
        var activeIndex = $("li.active", $("#navigation")).index();

        if (typeof $(this).attr('id') != "undefined") {

            if ($(this).attr('id') == "previous" && activeIndex > 1) {
                //set PREV Active Image
                $("li", $("#navigation")).removeClass('active');
                $("#navigation li:eq(" + (activeIndex - 1) + ")").attr('class', 'active');

            } else if ($(this).attr('id') == "next" && activeIndex < ($("li", $("#navigation")).length - 2)) {
                //set NEXT Active Image
                $("li", $("#navigation")).removeClass('active');
                $("#navigation li:eq(" + (activeIndex + 1) + ")").attr('class', 'active');
            }
        } else {
            //set Active Image which slide no is clicked    
            $("li", $("#navigation")).removeClass('active');
            $(this).attr('class', 'active');
        }
        //Check if Different Slide has been clicked or Move then only load..
        if (activeIndex != $("li.active", $("#navigation")).index()) {
            showSlide(); //Call to show active image
        }
    });

});
//Function to Show Current Active Image Slide
function showSlide() {
    //Get Current Index of Active LI
    var i = $("li.active", $("#navigation")).index();
    //Check Range of Current Index
    if (i > 0 && i < ($("li", $("#navigation")).length - 1)) {
        //FadeOut all Images
        $(".slide", $("#images")).fadeOut(1000);
        //FadeIn Only Current Active Indexed Slided
        $(".slide:eq(" + (i - 1) + ")", $("#images")).fadeIn(3000);

    }

}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8x